# Когда лучше использовать RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java

Разбираюсь с RandomAccessFile. Насколько я понял, плюсы его использования - возможность перемещения курсора по файлу и перепрыгивания сразу к нужному разделу. Что еще? В каких случая реально лучше его использовать?

Comment: когда у вас есть файл 5гигов а вам нужно только 4 первых байта или последних. Поэтому не целесообразно грузить весь файл в память а проще взять только нужные байты

Comment: спасибо. Доступно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас файл с чёткой структурой, то вы заранее знаете, откуда и что считывать. Возьмите любой формат устоявшийся. У файла есть заголовочная часть, есть часть с данными, где каждый блок с фиксированным размером.

С помощью `RandomAccessFile` вы может начать читать сразу с нужного места.

К примеру, считывание того же WAV файла.

Или, если вам нужно прочитать сколько-то последних байт файла (чтение логов, например). А логи бывают большие.

**P.S.** напомню, что операции ввода/вывода одни из самых медленных, поэтому желательно минимизировать работу с ними. С чем во многих случаях и помогает `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Очень помогли!

Comment: @МаксимБродский рад, что помогло ^_^